# html Unlimited hierarchy input to form

Tags: javascript, html, categories

I want to add form for adding new categories. Categories might have infinitive sub categories.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var max_fields = 15; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function (e) { //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if (x < max_fields) { //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="input_fields_wrap_sec"><input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Sub-Category title"/>\n\
                                <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Add Sub-Sub-Category" class="add_field_button" >\n\
                                <a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
                    ); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) { //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parent('div').remove();
        x--;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="POST">
   <div class="input_fields_wrap">
      <p>Please enter the Category Title</p>
      <input type="text" name="mytext[]" placeholder="Category title">
      <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Add Sub-Category" class="add_field_button" >
   </div>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Now I have form like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3U3NP.png) and when I press "add sub-sub category" it should appear new "sub-sub category" input with buttons: "add sub-sub-sub category" and "remove"

It should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smDPB.png), the deep of categories is infinitive

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you stuck on something specifically?

Comment: I tried to add "sub-sub-categories" field and buttons, and that sub-sub-category might have its own sub-categories. But when I am trying to press add sub-sub-category button the page is reloading.
I don't know how should I write in js to create category that might have its sub category, which can have their own sub categories and etc.

Comment: The problem is that when you call `$(add_button).click`, you attach a listener on **existing buttons**. Then you create some new buttons, but they do not have this listener attached ;) So when you click on them, they submit your form and that reloads the page! If I were you, I'd use `type=button` for my buttons, and `onclick="addSubCategory()"` where `addSubCatogery` will be your listener ;) Hope this helps!

Comment: instead of `submit` , use `button`

Comment: I think the final button needs to have type submit, but the inner ones not. Then preventDefault will also be unneccesary.

Comment: Aciu! Thanks for accepting my answer, please check my new improved fiddle for improved functionality - assuming you might want to submit the hierarchy to a server or alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Labas!

You could try something like this:

```
function getValueText(level) {

  let i = 0
  let text = "Add ";
  while (i < level) {
    text += "sub-"
    i++;
  }

  return text + "category";
}

function appendInnerCategory(level, element) {
  var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
  myDiv.className = "level-" + level
  var btn = document.createElement("input");
  btn.type = "button";
  btn.value = getValueText(level);
  btn.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    appendInnerCategory(level + 1, event.target.parentNode);
  });
  var textBox = document.createElement("input");
  textBox.type = "text";
  myDiv.appendChild(textBox);
  myDiv.appendChild(btn);
  element.appendChild(myDiv);
}

appendInnerCategory(0, document.querySelector('.wrapper'));
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7L382gow/

Updated fiddle to maintain a structure object, while manipulating the DOM.

Submit will print the resulting hierarchy to console.

http://jsfiddle.net/bqk6pmjg/

Comment: This is totally amazing.  Note though, I get a console error from the fiddle code.  It claims it fails to load http://jsfiddle.net/js/createStream.js.map . Though I do get a properly formed json object in the output.

Comment: I have worked out issues to the point where the console in both jsfiddle and the console in my django instance spits out exactly what I want, but the form never actually submits results.  I have a sanity check in my `form_valid` function that should print a simple string to the console when you click submit, but nothing comes out and there are no errors... What else do I need to actually submit the data to the server? Here's my jsfiddle mod/fork of your code (proof of concept before moving to django)... http://jsfiddle.net/hepcat72/d42k38j1/18/