# How can I dynamically create multi-level hierarchical forms in Django?

Tags: django, forms, formset

I'm building an advanced search page for a scientific database using Django.  The goal is to be able to allow some dynamically created sophisticated searches, joining groups of search terms with `and` & `or`.

I got part-way there by following [this example](https://aalvarez.me/posts/django-formsets-with-generic-formviews/), which allows multiple terms anded together.  It's basically a single group of search terms, dynamically created, that I can either and-together or or-together.  E.g.

- `<field1|field2> <is|is not|contains|doesn't contain> <search term> <->`
- `<+>`

...where `<->` will remove a search term row and `<+>` will add a new row.

But I would like the user to be able to either add another search term row, or add an and-group and an or-group, so that I'd have something like:

- `<and-group|or-group> <->`

  - `<field1|field2> <is|is not|contains|doesn't contain> <search term> <->`
  - `<+term|+and-group|_or-group>`

A user could then add terms or groups.  The result search might end up like:

- `and-group`

  - `compound` `is` `lysine`
  - `or-group`

    - `tissue` `is` `brain`
    - `tissue` `is` `spleen`
  - `feeding status` `is not` `fasted`

Thus the resulting filter would be like the following.

```
Data.objects.filter(Q(compound="lysine") & (Q(tissue=brain) | Q(tissue="spleen")) & ~Q(feeding_status="fasted"))
```

**Note - I'm not necessarily asking how to get the filter expression below correct - it's just the dynamic hierarchical construction component that I'm trying to figure out.**  Please excuse me if I got the `Q` and/or `filter` syntax wrong.  I've made these queries before, but I'm still new to Django, so getting it right off the top of my head here is pretty much guaranteed to be zero-chance.  I also skipped the model relationships I spanned here, so let's assume these are all fields in the same model, for simplicity.

I'm not sure how I would dynamically add parentheses to the filter expression, but my current code could easily join individual `Q` expressions with `and` or `or`.

I'm also not sure how I could dynamically create a hierarchal form to create the sub-groups.  I'm guessing any such solution would have to be a hack and that there are not established mechanisms for doing something like this...

Here's a screenshot example of what I've currently got working:

[image: non-hierarchical example]

***UPDATE***:

I got really far following [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736373/html-unlimited-hierarchy-input-to-form) I found.  I forked that fiddle and got this proof of concept working before incorporating it into my Django project:

http://jsfiddle.net/hepcat72/d42k38j1/18/

The console spits out exactly the object I want.  And there are no errors.  Clicking the search button works for form validation.  Any fields I leave empty causes a prompt to fill in the field.  Here's a demo gif:

[image]

Now I need to process the POST input to construct the query (which I think I can handle) and restore the form above the results - which I'm not quite sure how to accomplish - perhaps a recursive function in a custom tag?

Although, is there a way to snapshot the form and restore it when the results load below it?  Or maybe have the results load in a different frame?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I'm teaching a grandmother to suck eggs, but in case not, one of the features of the Python language may be useful.

```
foo( bar = 27, baz = None)
```

can instead be coded

```
args = {}
a1, a2 = 'bar', 'baz'
d[a1] = 27
d[a2] = None
foo( **args )
```

so an arbitrary Q object specified by runtime keys and values can be constructed `q1 = Q(**args)`

IIRC `q1 & q2` and `q1 | q2` are themselves Q objects so you can build up a filter of arbitrary complexity.

I'll also include a mention of [Django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) which is usually my answer to filtering questions like this one, but I suspect in this case you are after greater power than it easily provides. Basically,  it will "and" together a list of filter conditions specified by the user. The built-in ones are simple  `.filter( key=value)`, but by adding code you can create custom filters with complex Q expressions related to a user-supplied value.

As for the forms, a Django form is a linear construct, and a formset is a list of similar forms. I think I might resort to JavaScript to build some sort of tree representing a complex query in the browser, and have the submit button encode it as JSON and return it through a single text field (or just pick it out of `request.POST` without using a form). There may be some Javascript out there  already written to do this, but I'm not aware of it. You'd need to be sure that malicious submission of field names and values you weren't expecting doesn't result in security issues. For a pure filtering operation, this basically amounts to being sure that the user is entitled to get all data in  database table in any case.

There's a form  [JSONField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/forms/#jsonfield) in the Django PostgreSQL extensions, which validates that user-supplied (or Javascript-generated) text is indeed JSON, and supplies it to you as Python dicts and lists.

Comment: I currently construct an arbitrary series of `Q` statements that I supply to filter using *expression. That part, I have, though I'm not quite sure how to include arbitrary parenthesized groups, e.g. "`q1` & (`q2` | `q3`)". I envision a recursive function to do it, but first I need the data. So the bit I'm mainly after is the one you alluded to with the suggestion about JavaScript generating a text field from the submit button. But that skips over how I dynamically create the hierarchical search term form elements that define the parenthesized groups.

Comment: @hepcat72 As a proof of concept you could map a JSON dict onto `Q(**dict)` , JSON `[0, dict1, dict2, ...] `onto `Q(**dict1) | Q(**dict2) |...` and similarly with `[ 1, ...]` representing `&`. JSON Lists can contain lists so you can represent an arbitrarily complex query as JSON quite easily. Representing it in a good intuitive graphical way is the harder bit. I'd start by looking for somebody who has already written something similar in JavaScript!

Comment: You'd also have to represent negation in the JSON too somehow, e.g. `~Q(**dict)`. If I had a way to create the structure via GUI elements, I feel like creating a recursive function to construct the Q expression wouldn't be too hard. I like the suggestion of JavaScript to set a (hidden) text field, but the dynamic form elements to create the structure seems really difficult. I have searched quite a bit to see if someone has already worked it out. No luck so far.

Comment: @hepcat72 Ask another StackOverflow question aimed at JavaScript front-end coders? Writing the question will take a bit of thought. The structure sought is fairly similar to dynamically building something to represent a filesystem directory tree (which might be another thing to search). This is a very interesting question. I wish I had spare time!

Comment: For negation you'd just stuff another integer constant representing unary not in the JSON list in front of the dict representing the Q that you want negated. An int isn't a dict so easy to check.

Comment: Good search suggestion. I'll probably look into this on Monday: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50736373/html-unlimited-hierarchy-input-to-form

Comment: Well, it took me pretty much all week, and then some, but I finally have a working hierarchical search form.  I still have to construct and execute the query.  I had initially tried the jQuery from above, but it wasn't compatible with the pure javascript from the other dynamic formset generation code that takes advantage of the Django formset_factory class.  So I ended up essentially re-implementing it in pure javascript. I also have some javascript optimization to do.  Some of the form fields take a second to enter values into...

Comment: Here's a demo. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qzCO5a3lFKl3M42KFqdfXGrH-v6zDE29